# RoundedRectangleBorder not working with ListTile nor Card in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have this custom function that returns a card containing ListTile. I'm having some trouble with styling. I want to apply rounded corners either to card or ListTile (I just want rounded corners) as below.
It didn't work with me.

I tried to apply cardTheme to all cards in a customized theme in a separate file but doesn't work, also in my code underneath I wanted the card to be colored blue at the moment the user presses and the default ripple effect to show but couldn't. Also couldn't apply blue border around the card. something is going wrong with my styling

```
Card myCardListTile(MyScreen myScreen, BuildContext context) {
return Card(
  child: ListTile(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
        side: BorderSide(color: kColorOxfordBlue, width: 12)),
    // focusColor: kColorOxfordBlue,
    // hoverColor: kColorOxfordBlue,
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, myScreen.route);
    },
    title: Text(
      myScreen.title,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
      // TextStyle(),
    ),
  ),
);


Class AppTheme {  
static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
  cardTheme: CardTheme(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius:   BorderRadius.circular(18.0)),
),
);}
```

and in the main.dart I used AppTheme.lightTheme

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
  // code
```

Comment: also I couldn't increase the thickness of the border nor change its color .. something must be going wrong with me

Comment: Which flutter version are you using and do you want the card or the tile to have roundcorners?

Comment: flutter v 2.0.2
I want to create rounded corners to the card, I want to increase the width and the color of the card as well.
I tried roundcorners on both because it didn't work on any.

Comment: Could you add the code when you add the rounded corners to your card?

Comment: added in the edit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70469823/flutter-cards-roundedrectangleborder-not-working-in-flutter-web

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory to use list view? cause you can use other widgets like container inside card with rounded corners. For example

```
return Card(
  elevation: 10.0,
  color: Colors.blue,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
  ),
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 8.0),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('something here'),
        SizedBox(width: 4.0),
        Text('something other here'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

You can customize container as per your need, hope it helps..

Comment: I used listTile because it has onTap: () {}, otherwise I had to add GestureDecture

Comment: @KhaledMahmoud yes, you will need to add gesture detector for onTap().

Comment: the solution is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70469823/flutter-cards-roundedrectangleborder-not-working-in-flutter-web