# Flutter: Card's RoundedRectangleBorder not working in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, card

I tried to design some sample in Flutter Web

There is a issue that I can't apply RoundedRectangleBorder to a card because it's not shown

[image: screenshot]

See the above image where the main Card only having sharp borders . Why ?

Below my Code :

https://gist.github.com/RageshAntony/8ee93d338aec9e352f71c14f0c84f734

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Container` with a white background to your `Card` as follows

```
Card(
     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)), // THIS NOT APPLYING !!!
     elevation: 20,
     child:Container(
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
         color: Colors.white,
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
       ),
       child:Row(
       ----------------------
       ),
),
```

Comment: After I tried your code. But not worked in first attempt . Then I added some padding to the container your suggested. Then I got the round corners . Then I removed the Boxdecrotion and still retains the round corners.   So The need is to give some padding to the child of the Card to get rounded corners  . Thanks